# how to add categories in contact form 7 in dropdown menu

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, categories, contact-form

I am new to wordpress and I want the following kind of dropdown menu in my contact form 7.

Year
<2010>,<2011>,<2012>,<2013>,<2014>

Month
...,october,november,december

Date
....<27>,<28>,<29>,<30>,<31>

Here Year, Month and Date should be visible in dropdown menu but it should not get selected where as the options below that should be able to select

Pls suggest me as to how can I achieve this.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Please tell me clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it here: http://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/
Maybe you can create shortcode to populate the dates, instead of hard coding it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this:
`Select Year (required)
[select* year include_blank "2010" "2011" "2013" "2014"]` and you can repeat this for month and day.

Each of the items i.e. year, month and day is a new field.

Or alternatively, you could use the plugin **[Contact Form 7 Datepicker](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-datepicker)** to add a date picker field to your form